# Добавление поля при генерации таблицы многие ко многим Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

При создании базы ,если есть 2 таблицы с отношением многие ко многим .Entity Framwork создаёт  промежуточную таблицу.Как сделать , чтобы в данную промежуточную таблицу можно было добавить поле.Пример-2 таблицы Products,Orders .Необходимо хранить количество купленных товаров в каждом заказе-т.е.необходимо,чтобы в промежуточной табл были 3 поля(Order-Product-int).А так,создаётся только (Order-Product)

```
   public class Product
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Sale { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
    }

    public class Order
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
   public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public int ?EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer{ get; set; }
    public int ?CustomerId { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
    }
```

Comment: для связывания таблиц со связями многие ко многим нужно создать третью таблицу и указывать какой ID из первой соответствует записи из второй. поэтому EF создает таблицу Order-Product. ее трогать нельзя

Comment: [Join entity type configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration)